# How to apply jquery effect to element created by Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hello I have the following code in my view:

```
        <div data-bind="foreach: Elements">
            <div data-bind="attr:{id: id}">
                <img data-bind="attr:{src: ImageSource}" />
                <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But for each new element I want to add the jQuery effet like:

```
        $("#draggable").draggable();
```

Is there any way to subsribe to event that occures after element added to this list?

Comment: You could have a look at using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) if you want to keep the event subscription separate from knockout. `MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use custom bindings.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable= {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

    <div data-bind="foreach: Elements">
        <div data-bind="attr:{id: id}, draggable: {}">
            <img data-bind="attr:{src: ImageSource}" />
            <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Read more about it in the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html.